# How to make OpenAM to return jwt-token with simple username and password authentication

Tags: openam

My problem is that I want to configure Openam so that it returns a JWT-token when I use The simplest user name / password authentication. By default, it returns tokenId. But in my case, I need only JWT-token. I am using this endpoint for authentication: http://openam-01.domain.com:8080/openam/json/authenticate.

Thx!

Comment: Please include samples of code you've tried, in order to solve your own problem. This will make it easier for others to help solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenAM only issues a JWT when you are using 'stateless' / client based SSO session. If you need a standardised JWT, then you need to configure OpenAM as OIDC provider.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure OpenAM Security Token Service (STS) to exchange OpenAM authentication token to JWT.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Вот тут я перезадал вопрос в более развёрнутом виде : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66059390/configuration-openam-as-an-intermediate-authentication-rest-service-which-uses-a/66061312?noredirect=1#comment116828429_66061312

Можно вас попросить взглянуть и сказать , возможен ли такой сценарий ? В идеале пользователь приложения должен ввести логин и пароль один раз , на страничке , которую вернуло мое Java app . После чего его данные должны быть отправлены на openam инстанс , выступающий в качестве service provider и обещающийся по протоколу saml с адфс.